# For a one-class SVM, is it possible to figure out which parameter(s) in the detected outlier are anomalous?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

For example, I've trained my one-class SVM on miles per gallon, horsepower, and price:

(19.5, 140.0, 32000)
(24.1, 200.0, 40000)
(15.2, 101.2, 45000)

When I input:
(23.3, 105.2, 1000000)

it correctly gets identified as an outlier. But I'm also interested in *why* it is an outlier. Is there any way to get the SVM to tell me that the price is too high?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using non-linear one class SVM (and linear one does not really make sense) then the short answer is no. The outlier detection in one class svm is not a simple set of rules "feature x has to be between A and B". It is based on estimating the boundary of the dataset, thus the only valid answers would be "this is an outlier because in the metric induced by the kernel used, distance to the boundary is A, while acceptable one found during training is B".

In particular, what it means is that the decision is highly nonlinear, so (23.3, 105.2, 1000000) can be an outlier, (23.3, 105.2, 999999) inlier, and (23.3, 105.2, 999998) again an outlier, and (23.3, 105.2, 999997) again an inlier (with different training set, obviously).